# Is a new reference created by JVM when we access an instance variable?

Tags: java, reference, jvm

Say I have an instance variable pointing to an object.When I access that instance variable , does it create a new reference in memory?

```
public class Test {

    public Test2 t1= new Test2();

}

public class Test2 {


}


Test obj = new Test();
```

Does the line below create a new reference in memory: when we access obj.t1?

```
System.out.println(obj.t1==null)
```

Comment: "Does the line below create a new reference in memory" No. `obj.t1` was initialized on the `Test obj = new Test();` line.

Comment: Why do think it would _need_ do that?

Comment: A reference is a value. There can be a lot of copies of that value, not necessarily “in memory”. E.g., a reference can be stored in a CPU register. `System.out.println(obj.t1 == null);` temporarily creates a copy of the reference stored in `obj.t1`, just like it would temporarily create a copy of the int value when you do `System.out.println(obj.someIntField == 0);` This kind of “copying” is one of the most trivial operations…

Answer (score -1):

You have to consider the order of events in your example.

You are instantiating an instance of Test and assigning it to the reference obj.  In your example, t1 is an instance variable of Test so space is allocated in the heap for an instance of Test2 at the same time obj is instantiated.  The net effect is that all heap space is allocated when obj is assigned.

When you call println, you are using the existing reference to obj so no allocation takes place for either obj or the t1 reference through it.

Comment: There is no static initialisation here.